# Is there a way to create a triangle display of a HTML video tag using CSS border-radius?

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I am attempting to show a HTML video tag in a triangle display.  So, as opposed to the default rectangle display; a triangle.  Meaning, here's the default display:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Video Default</title>
</head>

<body>

  <video width="640" height="360" controls>
  <source src="https://durendel.com/event/theater/gravityphase.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

</body>

</html>
```

Notice how the default display is the rectangle form - my aim is to get the display in a `triangle` form - like this:

[image: Triangle Image Example]

I am trying to use CSS to accomplish this task, specifically `border-top-left radius` and `border-top-right-radius`, but I can only get it to curve.  Here's the code below:

```css
video {
  border-top-left-radius: 200px;
  border-top-right-radius: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Video</title>
</head>

<body>

  <video width="640" height="360" controls>
    <source src="https://durendel.com/event/theater/gravityphase.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>

</body>

</html>
```

The problem I'm running into, as you can see from the code snippet above, the left and right angles only curve as opposed to forming a point.  Therefore, is it possible to create a triangle display of a HTML video tag using CSS border-radius?  Or can someone provide some additional guidance as to what I should be using to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt this is possible with border-radius.

But you can achieve this with **clip-path**

```css
video {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Video</title>
</head>

<body>

  <video width="640" height="360" controls>
    <source src="https://durendel.com/event/theater/gravityphase.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the more appropriate property and for teaching me something new (+1).  I have never heard of clip-path before.